# Fix color to group when displaying selected groups in plot using RShiny

Tags: r, ggplot2, shiny

I'm just learning RShiny. I have created a very simple scatter plot with 3 groups (a,b,c). It works in that, e.g., when box "a" is selected, only group "a" is shown in the plot - same for combinations of groups. However, when only one group is shown, the points are in red, regardless of which group it is; when any 2 groups are selected, they are always in red and blue. Is there a way to make it so that the colors of the points are group specific, i.e. group "a" is always in red, "b" always in blue, and "c" always in green?

```
dat<-read_csv("publish_practice.csv")

dat %>% ggplot(aes(x=varX,y=varY,color=Group))+geom_point()

ui <- fluidPage(
  
  sidebarLayout(sidebarPanel(),mainPanel())
  
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      checkboxGroupInput(
        inputId="checked_groups",
        label="Which group(s) do you want to display?",
        choices=c("a","b","c"),
        selected=c("a","b","c")
      )
    ),
    mainPanel(
      plotOutput("scatter")
    )
  )
)

server <- function(input, output) {
  
  output$scatter<-renderPlot({
    
    plot_dat<-filter(dat, Group %in% input$checked_groups)
    
    ggplot(
      dat=plot_dat,
      aes(x=varX,y=varY,color=Group))+geom_point()

  }
  )
  
}


shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

I tried adding  `+  scale_color_manual(values=c("red","blue","green"))` to the ggplot code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were close.  Use `breaks = unique(dat$Group)` in the `scale_color_manual()`. Try this

```
dat <- iris %>%
  mutate(varX=Sepal.Length, varY = Petal.Length, Group=Species)

choices = unique(dat$Group)

ui <- fluidPage(

  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      checkboxGroupInput(
        inputId="checked_groups",
        label="Which group(s) do you want to display?",
        choices= choices, #c("a","b","c"),
        selected= choices #c("a","b","c")
      )
    ),
    mainPanel(
      plotOutput("scatter")
    )
  )
)

server <- function(input, output) {

  output$scatter<-renderPlot({

    plot_dat<-filter(dat, Group %in% input$checked_groups)

    ggplot(
      plot_dat,
      aes(x=varX,y=varY,color=Group))+geom_point() +
      scale_color_manual(breaks=choices, values=c("red","blue","green"))
  }
  )

}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Comment: Works with breaks = unique(dat$Group). Thanks!!